# Why doesn't a random sample all have the same value?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, statistical-inference

When constructing a random sample in Probability and Statistics, why doesn't the random sample all take on the same value?

For example, if $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is the random sample, why isn't the value $(X_1(\omega),\dots, X_1(\omega))$? Surely I must be missing something here. I thought the distribution characterizes the random variable so it should be that $X_1(\omega)=X_2(\omega)=\dots X_n(\omega)$. If $\omega$ is a person in a population, and $X_1(\omega)$ maps to the height of this person, wouldn't all o $(X_1(\omega),\dots, X_n(\omega))$ map to the height of that one person?

Comment: No, the distribution is not the same as the actual random variable as a function. It just tells you the probability that the random variable's value is in some set. For a concrete example, if your sample space is $(0,1)^n$ with the Lebesgue measure then $X_i(\omega)=\omega_i$ is a random sample of independent $U(0,1)$ variables.

Comment: That said, *one* random variable without the context of any other random variables or events is characterized by its distribution. But if you have several then they need a joint distribution.

Comment: @Ian Ah that makes sense. So the random vector is actually an element of the n-fold product space of the population?

Comment: Not necessarily; realistically a probability space should be viewed as an abstract thing and random variables on it get specified by their joint distribution. I just wanted to give a nice concrete example to make the distinction more transparent.

Comment: @Ian When I add two random variables, are they added pointwise on $\Omega$, as in $X+Y(\omega):=X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$ or are they added $X+Y(\omega_1,\omega_2)=X(\omega_1)+Y(\omega_2)$?

Comment: It's the same $\omega$ everywhere. Don't take that product example too seriously; explicit probability space constructions are very uncommon.

Comment: @Ian Ok they are uncommon. Does that mean that the single $\omega$ would implicitly be a vector as in your example? You're just saying dont think too much about the probability space?

Comment: In my exact example it is a vector. But don't take that example too seriously; realistically $\omega$ is an abstract element of an abstract set.

Comment: There are posts about this on cross validated. For example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450215/how-to-interpret-sum-of-two-random-variables-that-cross-domains